# Proof of density inequality

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities

I was wondering if there is an easy way to find sufficient conditions for the following inequality to hold

$$
\int f(x,y)^2 \:\mathrm{d}x \:\mathrm{d}y - \int f(x)^2 f(y)^2 \:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y \geq 0,
$$

where $f$ is the density function. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: _Equality_ will hold if $X$ and $Y$ are _independent_ random variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the case of continuous r.v.'s, we are asking under which conditions

$$\int\int f(x,y)^2 \:\mathrm{d}x \:\mathrm{d}y - \int\int f(x)^2 f(y)^2 \:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y \;\;?\geq ? \;\;0$$

Obviously, it holds trivially as an equality if the r.v.'s are independent. If they are not independent we ask, using $f(x,y) = f(x\mid y)f(y)$,

$$ \int\int f(x\mid y)^2f(y)^2 \:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y  - \int\int f(x)^2 f(y)^2 \:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y \;\;?\geq ? \;\;0$$

$$\Rightarrow \int\int [f(x\mid y)-f(x)][f(x\mid y)+f(x)]f(y)^2 \:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y \geq 0$$

All these are densities, and so non-negative. This means that a *sufficient* (although not necessary) condition is that

$$ f(x\mid y)-f(x) >0$$ for the whole support,
while a *necessary* (but not sufficient) condition is that this inequality holds for at least *some* of the support (the inequality is strict because we are in the sub-case of dependent r.v.s).

This sufficient condition can be written as

$$ f(x, y) > f(x)f(y)$$

for the whole support. But if it should hold for the whole support, then we should also have

$$\int \int f(x, y)\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y > \int \int f(x)f(y)\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y$$

$$\Rightarrow 1 >1 $$
which is impossible. So at least at such level of generality, it appears that no sufficient conditions may be stated.

Comment: Could you explain how you got from $$p(x,y) \leq p(y), \;\; p(x,y) \leq p(x),\;\;\forall x, y$$ to $$p(x,y)^2 \leq p(y)^2p(x)^2,\;\; \forall (x,y)$$ a little more? For example, if $p(x,y) = 0.1, p(x)=p(y)=0.2$ then $$p(x,y)^2 = 0.01  \geq p(y)^2p(x)^2 = 0.04^2 = 0.0016$$ and not the other way around.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I cannot explain it because it obviously does not hold in general. Thanks. I am editing the answer.

Comment: Exactly, it should not hold in general, but it can be verified that it hold if $f$ is Gaussian density. So there has to be a broader set of function for which it holds and I hoped that this set can be represented by some sufficient conditions.

Comment: However, maybe it can be easier to show the if the following holds $\int f(x,y)^2dxdy - \int f(x,y)f(x)f(y)dxdy\geq0$???.

Comment: It will lead you to the same prospective sufficient condition, which cannot hold. I cannot see any possible sufficient condition at that level of generality at least, although, there are certainly, wiser people here.

Comment: I see that. But how can it be true for the Gaussian distribution? Could that be possible that it holds for the whole expnential family?

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the case of the Gaussian distribution? I would like to search this a bit more.

Comment: For the Gaussian density: assume that $\sigma_x$ is the st. deviation of X and $\sigma_y$ of Y, and $\rho$ is the correlation between variables. Then using the multivariate normal (see page 6 from https://www.cis.rit.edu/class/simg713/Lectures/Lecture713-11-4.pdf), we can find that $\int f(x,y)^2 dxdy - \int f(x)^2f(y)^2dydx$ is equal $(4\pi\sigma_x \sigma_y)^{-1} [(1-\rho^2)^{1/2}-1]$, which is equal 0 only for independent variables.